# PHP multidimensional array conversion using array_map/array_walk functions

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
$userList = array(
    0 => array('id' => 1000, 'first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Smith'),
    1 => array('id' => 1001, 'first_name' => 'Sam', 'last_name' => 'Johnson'),
);
```

I want to convert it to the array like:

```
$userData = array(
    1000 => 'John Smith',
    1001 => 'Sam Johnson',
);
```

It's quite obvious for me how to implement this using foreach loop, but I wonder if it's possible to do this with PHP array functions like array_map or array_walk. Please use PHP 5.3 for the callback function. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since those functions only work on the array *values*, getting them to set the *key* in the new array is somewhat awkward. One way to do it is:

```
$arr = array_combine(
    array_map(function ($i) { return $i['id']; }, $arr),
    array_map(function ($i) { return "$i[first_name] $i[last_name]"; }, $arr)
);
```

This is a case where a `foreach` is much more appropriate.

Comment: Okay, now I'm convinced that `foreach` suits much better in such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

A minor trick from the functional programming.

```
$arr = array_reduce(
  $arr,
  function ($result, $item) {
    $result[$item['id']] = $item['first_name'] . ' ' . $item['last_name'];
    return $result;
  },
  array()
);
```

See [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array-reduce).

Comment: Nice one. Not sure it's really any better than a `foreach` though. ;)

Comment: I usually use 4 spaces for intendation, what makes it _slightly_ better readable. Also I would use objects instead, what would result in something like `return array_merge($result,array($user->id => $user->getFullname());` as callback. However: Don't know either :D

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
<?php

function convertArray ( $array ) {

    $newUserList = array();
    foreach ( $array as $value ) {
        $newUserList[ $value[ 'id' ] ] = $value[ 'first_name' ] . ' ' . $value[ 'last_name' ];
    }

    return $newUserList;

}   

$userList = array(
    0 => array( 'id' => 1000, 'first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Smith' ),
    1 => array( 'id' => 1001, 'first_name' => 'Sam', 'last_name' => 'Johnson' )
);

$newUserList = convertArray( $userList );

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1000] => John Smith
    [1001] => Sam Johnson
)
```